# MVC Single Sign On: How to get Userdata from DB before the page is going to be loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following issue:

I am working on a built of an intranet webpage with single sign on. 
In my Home Controller, before the Index page is going to be loaded, I take the Windows UserName of the User via

```
System.Environment.Username
```

Then I connect to my database and get the information (like department and lastname, fullname) of this user.

These information will be stored in public variables and then they will be shown in my navbar. For that I use Razor and write in the section of my layout:

```
<li class="user-header">
    <img src="~/dist/img/profile.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        <p>@Projectname.Controllers.HomeController.username
           <small>@Projectname.Controllers.HomeController.department</small>
       </p>
</li>
```

So there is an picture of the user (avatar) and then there should stay the firstname, lastname and the department.

But here is the problem. This works only if the user types in the url to the home page (localhost order localhost/home).

But if he types in for example (localhost/dashboard) the HomeController is not going to be invoked and then the area, where the username and department should stay, is empty (see attachments).

[Target: Should always looks like this, no matter from which point user accesses the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9o0A.png)

[This is how it is at the moment, when the site is not accessed through the HomeController.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNXPg.png)

So can you give me some hints, how I should proceed to realize my target? I have spend already 3 days to fix this "bug", which is actually no bug.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `System.Environment.Username` will return the the identity of the application pool, not the user who accessed the web site. You need to implement Windows Authentication and use, for example, `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: `System.Environment.Username` rarely used in MVC context to give user identity information on runtime. `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` more preferable on this case, providing the user authentication set to `<authentication mode="Windows">`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes, the authentication mode is already in windows. During the fact, that this is an intranet page, I have to go through windows authentication, to prove whether the user is in our company domain or not. If yes, then he is able to see this page. There is no problem with the autenthication. The problem I have is that I want to get "meta-data" no matter from which page the user accesses this application.

Comment: @Azeristar, You cannot use `System.Environment.Username` - your just running in local host so you see your name, but as soon as you publish this, you will see the server name, not the name of the user who navigated to the page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh ok, thanks for the hint. But nevertheless, How can I take the part where the Userinformation will be taken from the database, before no matter which controller will be requested?

Comment: Multiple ways, for example: Create a ChildActionOnly method that looks up the database based on `User.Identity.Name` and returns a partial view with the users details. Then in your layout use `@Html.Action(...)` to call that method so the partial is renedered on every page using that layout